# Perl Moose method attributes

Tags: perl

Does Moose have a way to get the class methods attributes. I learned from my previous questions here that some standalone modules like Sub::Talisman can get the module attributes.

If I run code below I get error "Invalid CODE attribute: Public at ..."

```
#============================
package BaseClass;
use Moose; 

#============================
package SubClass;
use Moose;
extends qw(BaseClass);

sub greet : Public {
    my $self = shift;
    printf("Hello world.");
}
#============================
package main;

my $object = SubClass->new();

# I need to get the Public attribute of the sub greet in the SubClass package.
# if the sub has a Public attribute, call it, otherwise, die.
# does Moose have some methods to get the attributes, I know some other modules like
# Sub::Talisman can get the sub's attributes.
$object->greet();
#============================
```

I need to get the Public attribute of the sub greet in the SubClass package.
If the sub has a Public attribute, I will do something, otherwise, something else.

Does Moose have some methods to get the attributes, I know some other modules like
Sub::Talisman can get the sub's attributes.

Comment: You might find [this cookbook entry](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Meta/PrivateOrPublic_MethodMetaclass.pod) interesting. It shows how public/private methods could be implemented in Moose, but doesn't add any pretty syntax like attributes.

Comment: I need to get the attribute myself and decided if it is Public as I marked it to run it to the caller which could be web browser.

Comment: The vast majority of method privacy implementations on CPAN (the Moose cookbook entry included) are just glorified versions of `die if caller ne ...`. As far as I'm concerned, this shows a misunderstanding of the purpose and benefits of true method privacy. If you want true private methods in Perl, stick a coderef in a lexical variable. If you want private attributes, check out [Lexical::Accessor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lexical::Accessor).

Comment: @tobyink I do not want a private methods inside the class, I want just to mark some methods as "web" safe or public access safe. So all I need is to read the mark of that method and decide what to do based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [MooseX::MethodAttributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX%3a%3aMethodAttributes) which integrates attribute introspection stuff into the Moose metaobject protocol.

However, the particular error you are getting will not be solved by that. To eliminate that error you need to define an attribute called `:Public`, so that Perl knows this attribute exists. [Sub::Talisman](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub%3a%3aTalisman) and [Attribute::Handlers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Attribute%3a%3aHandlers) are modules that could be used to define the attribute.

Comment: and how do I define the attribute :Public and how to read it, this is my question.

Comment: MooseX::MethodAttributes is a good solution since I am already using Moose. It is as easy as using `my $attr = MyApp->meta->get_method('Log')->attributes; # ["Bar", "Baz('corge')"]`.